# How do I kill main\parent task through background job?

Tags: powershell, parallel-processing, background, jobs

I have a requirement where I need to kill\stop main task if it has been running for a long time. I am thinking of creating a background job that monitors the time and kills the main job after timeout with proper message but I'm not sure how to do that.

Something like this..

```
    function Kill-MainTask{
      $sb = { 
      Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
      throw "main task should end"  
       }
      $job1 = Start-Job -ScriptBlock $sb 
      Write-Host "main task running"
      Start-Sleep -Seconds 10
      #This statement should not run
      Write-Host "main task not finished"
    }
    Kill-MainTask
```

When I call Kill-MainTask function it should print "mian task running" but after 5 seconds should throw.

Comment: $job1 is never called. You assign info to the variable but never use it anywhere.

Comment: And that is my question, how do I use that info? My main job is doing a lot of things and if it takes longer than 5 seconds I want to properly kill the main job.

Comment: You could flip it around. You have your initial script call `Start-Job $MainTask` and then, because it has the Job object, you can then check to see if it has finished in 5 seconds. Since you have the Job object, you can then also kill it.

Comment: I can't really flip because as the main task runs I need to show output on console to the user. If I run it as a job I won't be able to show the progress which is not an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several existing samples that show how to use this main and child job monitoring use case. See the below sample and resource links.

[Monitoring the Progress of a PowerShell Job](https://thesurlyadmin.com/2014/06/23/monitoring-the-progress-of-a-powershell-job)

[Quick Tip To Find Out What Your Background Jobs Are Doing](http://Start-Process%20'http://learn-powershell.net/2011/11/04/quick-tip-to-find-out-what-your-background-jobs-are-doing')

> Example:
>
> This is a simple script that create 5 background jobs (as
>   defined by $Num).  After submitting we’ll begin monitoring the
>   progress of the job.  We define $TotProg as 0 to start, then query the
>   StatusDescription–
>
> and since this returns an array we only want the
>   last element, hence the -1 element reference–and add it to our
>   $TotProg.  After that we check if $TotProg is greater than 0
>   (otherwise you’ll get a divide by zero error), display our progress
>   bar, wait a few seconds and loop again.  Go ahead and run the code
>   (don’t step through it in an ISE, to really see what I mean you have
>   to just run it).

```
$Num = 5

$Jobs = @()
ForEach ($Job in (1..$Num))
{   $Jobs += Start-Job -ScriptBlock { 
        $Count = 1
        Do {
            Write-Progress -Id 2 -Activity "Background Job" -Status $Count -PercentComplete 1
            $Count ++
            Start-Sleep -Seconds 4
        } Until ($Count -gt 5)
    }
}
$Total = $Num * 5

Write-Progress -Id 1 -Activity "Watching Background Jobs" -Status "Waiting for background jobs to started" -PercentComplete 0
Do {
    $TotProg = 0
    ForEach ($Job in $Jobs)
    {   Try {
            $Info = 
            $TotProg += ($Job | Get-Job).ChildJobs[0].Progress.StatusDescription[-1]
        }
        Catch {
            Start-Sleep -Seconds 3
            Continue
        }
    }
    If ($TotProg)
    {   Write-Progress -Id 1 -Activity "Watching Background Jobs" -Status "Waiting for background jobs to complete: $TotProg of $Total" -PercentComplete (($TotProg / $Total) * 100)
    }
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 3
} Until (($Jobs | Where State -eq "Running").Count -eq 0)

$Jobs | Remove-Job -Force

Write-Progress -Id 1 -Activity "Watching Background Jobs" -Status "Completed!  $Total of $Total" -PercentComplete 100
Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
Write-Progress -Id 1 -Activity "Watching Background Jobs" -Status "Completed!  $Total of $Total" -Completed
```

Or this approach

[Creating A Timeout Feature In Your PowerShell Scripts](https://blog.ipswitch.com/creating-a-timeout-feature-in-your-powershell-scripts)

```
# define a timeout
$Timeout = 10 ## seconds

# Code for the scriptblock
$jobs = Get-Job
$Condition = {param($jobs) 'Running' -notin $jobs.State }
$ConditionArgs = $jobs

# define how long in between checks
$RetryInterval = 5

# Start the timer
$timer = [Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::StartNew()

# Invoke code actions
while (($timer.Elapsed.TotalSeconds -lt $Timeout) -and (& $Condition $ConditionArgs)) {

    ## Wait a specific interval
    Start-Sleep -Seconds $RetryInterval

    ## Check the time
    $totalSecs = [math]::Round($timer.Elapsed.TotalSeconds,0)
    Write-Verbose -Message "Still waiting for action to complete after [$totalSecs] seconds..."
}


# The action either completed or timed out. Stop the timer.
$timer.Stop()

# Return status of what happened
if ($timer.Elapsed.TotalSeconds -gt $Timeout) 
{ throw 'Action did not complete before timeout period.' } 
else 
{ Write-Verbose -Message 'Action completed before the timeout period.'  }
```